# Using Infer.Net models in an ASP.Net web service

Tags: asp.net, azure-worker-roles, bayesian-networks, inference-engine

I'm building an ASP.Net Web API 2 web service in Azure to give access to an [Infer.Net](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/) naive Bayes model. There are two modes for starting up the model: building the model from scratch or loading the last-saved state of the model. The latter is faster than the former, but neither is near-instantaneous. Web service calls need to be immediate and near-stateless. The two ways I can imagine associating the running model with the web API are to use [ASP.Net's application state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) or to use an [Azure Worker Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj149831.aspx) and communicate between the web service methods and the running worker role using queues.

What is the best practice for associating a running Infer.Net model with a web service API?

Comment: I couldn't find an Infer.Net tag

Comment: I've asked this [on the Infer.Net forums](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2c86705-81b8-4418-8b92-f6b59fd43c1f/using-infernet-models-in-an-aspnet-web-service?forum=infer.net) too